# 2 jquery scripts work fine seperatly... but when on same page neither work

Tags: jquery, fancybox, nivo-slider

Hi ive got 2 scripts 1 is fancy box popup inline peice of text and the other is a nivo image slider, they both work great by them selves but when but in the head of the page to run them neither work, any ideas ? heres the two scripts

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#various1").fancybox();   
});
```

and the slider...

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect:'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        directionNavHide:false, // Only show on hover    
        pauseOnHover:true, // Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance:true, // Force manual transitions
   });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what does or does not work? Is there any errors reported in the console? Also I see an error in your JavaScript the });}); is commented on on the slider. Put it on the next line.

Comment: What kind of JS error you got?

Comment: the second script has problem. you commented the ending brackets..

Comment: Remove the comma form the last line in the nivoSlider ... from `manualAdvance:true,` to `manualAdvance:true`

Comment: Also, remove the last comma from the nivoSlider option hash.

Answer (score 3):

Because there is a syntax error on the second script.

This should work.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
      effect: 'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
      directionNavHide: false, // Only show on hover    
      pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
      manualAdvance: true // Force manual transitions
    });
});
```

Also, I removed the last comma, as there are no more things listed and that comma may cause problems on some browsers.

Comment: intriguing: could you point out where was the syntax error? so we all can learn. Personally I don't see any difference between your code and the code posted above (except some spaces and the last trialing comma).

Comment: @JFK: the OP edited the question and corrected the wrong part of code, probably a typo during copy and paste while creating the question. The last comma is the only remaining problem now, as browsers such as old IE will generate a syntax error and won't execute the script.

Comment: This the case where OP's shouldn't edit the questions, we'll never know then. thanks!

Comment: @JFK actually it's best to read the question preview better before decide to post the question/answer, so you don't have to edit later... anyway you can click on the "edited xx days ago" link next to the OP profile box to see each and every edit that's been made to the question/answer. As you can see the first version of the question was really bad formatted... ManseUK helped readability by editing.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for that problem you'll find plenty of people with the same problem. Both tools are jQuery plugins so probably they have some conflicting code.

If you can't fix the error inside the plugins you might want to substitute one of them, e.g. using [nivoo slider](http://mootools.net/forge/p/nivoo_slider), a port of nivo from jQuery to Mootools.